# EditText get selection index with button click

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to implement tag-supported plain text editor.

For that, like stackoverflow input panel, when user selects text and clicks "bold" button then the selected text is replaced into `<b> selected text </b>` or `** selected text **`.

To get the start and end index of text, below code is used.

```
int startIndex =  _editTextContent.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = _editTextContent.getSelectionEnd();
```

but, when I click the button, even the GUI still shows text selection marker, the same start and end values are given.

I found that `Button` works fine but `ListView` with its item click events are not give proper value.
I use [HListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView) for adapting to various resolution. FYI, the control is almost same as `ListView` control.

The item Click event is as below.

```
public void onItemClick(it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
if (_keys.getList().get(position).getId().equals("bold")) {
        try {
            _editTextContent.requestFocus();
            int startIndex =  _editTextContent.getSelectionStart();
            int endIndex = _editTextContent.getSelectionEnd();
            if (startIndex != endIndex){
                _editTextContent.getText().replace(startIndex, endIndex, "**" + _editTextContent.getText().subSequence(startIndex, endIndex) + "**");
                _editTextContent.setSelection(endIndex + 4);

            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

may be the button click changes focus to button so that the EditText control is switched from *selection* status to normal status.

What is the workaround to do?

Note that I'm develping based on the API 9, so that I cannot use `textIsSelectable` attribute.

Comment: what happens when ?you click the button? do you expect some text to be selected? not clear from your question

Comment: @gaurav5430 // I attached additional code, but not so special. The text is *already* selected by the user. I want to get the selected text and attach tags around them when I click the button.

Comment: @gaurav5430 // I add more detail code, and apologize that I wrote a vague description. A Button control works fine, but ListView item click is not working.

Comment: How are you using the ListView?  It seems like the ListView could be central to your problem but you've only mentioned it briefly.  Your code for replacing the selected text works fine for me outside of any ListView.